# Python using json to read a string with emoticons

Tags: python, json, facebook, emoticons

I have a giant `.json` file

Im reading it with

```
json_data=open('file.json')
data = json.load(json_data)


for item in data['payload']['actions']:
    print item['author']
    print item['action_id']
    print item['body']
json_data.close()
```

eventually one of the `item['body']` contains this string (which are actually facebook emoticons) :

`words words stuff stuff\ud83c\udf89\ud83c\udf8a\ud83c\udf87\ud83c\udf86\ud83c\udf08\ud83d\udca5\u2728\ud83d\udcab\ud83d\udc45\ud83d\udeb9\ud83d\udeba\ud83d\udc83\ud83d\ude4c\ud83c\udfc3\ud83d\udc6c`

which makes it give this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "curse.py", line 15, in <module>
    print item['body']
  File "C:\python27\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 35-63: character maps to <undefined>
```

Is there a way to make it ignore these?

Comment: You mean besides try/except blocks?

Comment: I would like it to still print the rest of the string. There are words before the characters it wont print. I guess I should have specified that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `string.printable`

```
import string

try:
    print item['body']
except UnicodeEncodeError:
    print(''.join(c for c in item['body'] if c in string.printable))
```